# BigQuery: counts iterations per work block

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need a query in `BIGQUERY` that can count the number of iterations per work block.

When it gets to 'done', a block of work will be finished.

I have this table:

```
version_id      status
ghfjghj         pending
gsffsg          pending
jhkukiul        done
fsgsfgffgsf     pending
nmyumuju        done
```

and I want this result:

```
block   iterations
   1            3
   2            2
```

Comment: Do you want to count how many are "pending" and "done"? 3 -> "pending", 2 -> "done"? What is the basis for the values in column "block"?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of statuses it takes to reach every new **done** status. It works if you have PK, or some unique ID column.
Sample data:

```
with cte  as (
  select 1 as id,'pending' as status
  union all select 2,'pending'
  union all select 3, 'done'
  union all select 4,'pending'
  union all select 5, 'done'
)
```

Enumerating each Done status (block) and all statuses (rn).

```
,
cte2 as (
  select 
    row_number () over (partition by status order by id) as block,
    row_number () over (order by id) as rn,
  id,status
  from cte)
```

Calculating the index difference between this and previous Done status, for each Done status to find the number of other statuses till done, which appears to be iteration number.

```
select 
  block,
  rn-lag(rn,1,0) over (order by block) as iteration
  from cte2
  where status = 'done'
  order by 1
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b28da/2368)
The fiddle is for T-SQL, but works for Bigquery SQL too.